# calculate profit 10% from buy price

Tags: mysql

I have this script calculates profit

Steps :

- barangbeli = harsat / diameter
- p1 = barangbeli * 10
- p2 = prof / 100
- result = barangbeli + profit;

thanks

```
CREATE VIEW tbkeluar as 
SELECT  mbarang.kdbrg, mbarang.nmbrg, mbarang.spek,if(SUM(bkeluar.qty), SUM(bkeluar.qty), 0)as qty,(tbmasuk.harsat/mbarang.diameter) as hargabeli, ((hargabeli*10)/100 )+hargabeli) as profit
LEFT JOIN bkeluar on mbarang.kdbrg = bkeluar.kdbrg group by mbarang.kdbrg
```

i have error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') as profit from mbarang
LEFT JOIN bkeluar on mbarang.kdbrg = bkeluar.kdbrg gro' at line 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you received should be helpful enough to know whats wrong.

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') as profit from mbarang LEFT JOIN bkeluar on mbarang.kdbrg = bkeluar.kdbrg gro' at line 2

Based from the error message, `MySQL` says that you have a **syntax error** because of this character `)`, with some characters appended for you to locate it: `) as profit from mbarang`

As you can see from your `SELECT` statement, you have an extra `)`

```
SELECT  mbarang.kdbrg
    , mbarang.nmbrg
    , mbarang.spek
    ,if(SUM(bkeluar.qty), SUM(bkeluar.qty), 0)as qty
    ,(tbmasuk.harsat/mbarang.diameter) as hargabeli
    , ((hargabeli*10)/100 )+hargabeli) as profit
                                     ^ delete this extra parenthesis
```

Comment: @YusrilIhzaM it's okay mate, I went through the same before ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your SELECT statement (in CREATE VIEW) is missing its FROM clause. Do you mean `FROM mbarang`?

You're also probably missing at least one more JOIN; the table `tbmasuk` is mentioned in the `SELECT` clause, but isn't mentioned anywhere else in the statement.